# YugabyteDB deployment in 2 datacenters

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have two different Datacentres, I want the app to write simultaneously to the database on both data centers. Both the instances in the Primary and Secondary datacentres should be active and accept writes and should replicate synchronously or async. However, ACID property should be maintained so that data is consistently read at both sites. The database in Primary should have all data that Secondary has and vice versa. The latency between the datacenters is 40ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Using a single, multi-region YugabyteDB cluster stretched across datacenters. YB uses synchronous replication within a single cluster.. this uses quorum (consensus) protocol.

For this deployment, because of the use of RAFT protocol, an odd number of data centers, typically 3, is recommended so that you can tolerate a datacenter failure and still be active. Disadvantage: This deployment will generally have higher latency for write operation. The further apart the DCs are, the higher the latency will be.
At the tablet level, leaders have to coordinate the writes. So no matter which node / DC you are coming from. The request will first have to be routed to the leader of the tablet. This could add 40ms if the leader for shard was in DC1 but your write request (i.e. app is running in DC(⅔)). You will not have this penalty if you are primarily writing from one DC and you pick that DC as the preferred zone to keep all your leaders(by default).
On top of that, the number of network round-trips depends on whether the operation is a fast-path (single-shard) transaction - e.g., a simple single-row INSERT (in which case about another 40ms). Or, if it involves a distributed transaction (e.g., a multi-row INSERT or an INSERT to a table with one more secondary index) -- this case will involve about two network round-trips.. so closer to 80-100ms.

Option 2: Using two YugabyteDB clusters.. one in DC1 and one in DC2. Each is RF=3, and asynchronously replicating to each other. Both clusters can take writes, and latency of writes will stay in intra-DC latencies (so it'll be much faster than option 1). However, you will not have immediate consistency at both sites with async replication, so no full ACID implementation. Furthermore, if you are taking writes on both sites and doing async replication bidirectionally, then care has to be exercised. If the two clusters are touching an unrelated set of keys/records, then less of an issue. If they are updating the same records, then the semantics is just "latest writer wins", and not going to be ACID. Basically, bidirectional async replication should be used carefully/has these caveats as you can imagine due to the very nature of async replication.